# How to Compare Date and Time in firestore query in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getData() async {
var now = new DateTime.now();
var formatter = new DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
String formattedDate = formatter.format(now);
String time = new DateFormat.jm().format(now);
var firestore = Firestore.instance;
print(formattedDate);
print(time);
QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore
    .collection("LiveGames")
    .where("Title", isEqualTo: "Solo").where(DateTime.parse("GameData.Date"), isLessThan: DateTime.parse(formattedDate))
    .where(DateTime.parse("GameData.Time"), isLessThan: DateTime.parse(time))
    .getDocuments();
  return qn.documents;
}
```

I am trying to compare the date and time from firestore which i have saved in the date and time in string values in firebase and i want to compare that date and time and while fetching the documents but i am getting error The getter length was called on null
Receiver: null
Tried Calling : length from the FutureBuilder

I think DateTime.parse("GameData.Date") from this line i am getting the error becuase this determines the Key not the value

[image]

Comment: where is GameData class, need more code

Comment: GameData is not class it is in the firestore

Comment: what is GameData? a Map?

Comment: It is map in the firestore

Comment: And i have to compare GameData.Time  value with current time value

Comment: Every dateTime has isAfter() isBefore() many other helper functions

Comment: Firstore supports timestamp..check their documentation, don't use string format

Answer (score 0):

while storing use in place of String

```
gameData["date"] = DateTime(2020,5,21).toIso8601String()
```

while parsing try

```
DateTime.parse("${gameData["date"]}");
```

if you use DateTime, the stored string will be in the format of `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.mmmuuu`
which will be parsed without an error

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: OP never accepted any answer, I'll fix the issue once it's accepted

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer anyways